# How were Wikipedia's orbital simulations made?

Tags: orbit, spacecraft, software

Pretty simple question; what software is used on Wikipedia to make these simulations? Some examples below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/59931/which-programs-are-used-to-calculate-delta-v-and-launch-dates-to-get-to-other-ob

Comment: Wikipedia is a community maintained online encyclopedia. The content that you see on Wikipedia was created by millions of different people. If you have a question about how a particular animated GIF was created there will normally be a source reference showing who created it or where it came from, although that in itself will likely not tell you what software they used. If you want someone here to comment on it you need to provide a link to the Wikipedia page that you are looking at.

Comment: @StevePemberton I’d have to disagree with you on that. While I agree that Wikipedia is community maintained, these GIFs are _fairly consistent_ across pages. They seem to be derived from SPK Data, but nothing about the software. Anyway, links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist#/media/File:Animation_of_Voyager_1_trajectory.gif

Comment: hi-bye125 - I'm not trying to get into semantics or say that your question isn't valid, in fact it's an interesting question. I'm just pointing out that it has nothing to do with Wikipedia. No more than if you saw a photo that someone uploaded onto Wikipedia and wondered what type of lens was used.

Comment: There appears to be a single wikipedia user responsibe for both of those images, Phoenix7777. It looks like it's something generated by one of the tools at the Nasa Horizons data and possibly one of the tools at NASA;s Solar System dynamics page, ssd.jpl.nasa.gov , but am unsure which was used, or how the animations were generated.

Comment: One way you could do it, is use JPL Horizons to generate the data, then use any programming language to graph each individual frame, and then FFMPEG to stitch them all together.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the only person who can answer it is the Wikipedia user who uploaded the images, and it is unlikely they will read the question here.

Comment: Phoenix7777 has been repeatedly asked this question on their talk page to no avail as well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Phoenix7777#Orbital_Visualization_Software

Comment: Whoops, also meant to say: I disagree with the close voters. The question is well-posed, on-topic (though I admit I'm not fond of a lot of the software-specific questions here, we've decided they're on topic) and seems unlikely to attract low-quality answers. Closing it just means we won't get a good answer if someone has one.

Comment: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/tools/sbdb_lookup.html#/ can do simple 3D orbit plots of minor bodies (and nearby planets), but they warn that they are  just simple 1-body calculations, with no other gravitational interactions.

Comment: I have a Sage/Python script that does 3D orbit plots of multiple bodies using Horizons, but they aren't animated. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49823/16685

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found it (though for a different image from the same user--but it's almost certainly still the answer)! from [Phoenix7777's Wikimedia commons page](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Phoenix7777#New_Horizons_flyby_-_Hydra_missing.):

> I wrote the program.

There's also the note (because of the request to add Plutonian moon Hydra to the visualization) that, at least as of January 2019, that program was limited to visualizing five bodies and a spacecraft.

Based on the rest of that page, they do a significant amount of other data visualization and mapping as well.

Comment: It appears the program isn't available for download. Bummer.